# representing a vector component as column matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, mathematical-physics

Any vector $\vec{v} \in$ a vector space V can be represented as a standard basis expansion $\vec{v}=v^{i}\vec{e_{i}}$.
The element $v^{i}$ are elements in the field $\mathbb{F}$ of reals.

Because the components $v^{i}$ of a vector wrt to basis $\beta$ is unique, once a basis $\beta$ has been chosen, any vector $\vec{v}$ can be represented by its component $v^{i}$ or equivalently as an n-tuple element $\left ( v^{1},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,v^{n} \right ) \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$.

My notes proceed to mention that the vector $\vec{v}$ can thus be represented as a column matrix made from its component denoted by $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$.

I.e.,

**v**=$\begin{bmatrix}
v^{1}\\v^{2} 
\\\cdot 
\\ \cdot
\\ \cdot
v^{n}
\end{bmatrix}$

For some reason, I am unable to make the connect with representing the components of the vector as a column matrix. Perhaps, there is a lack in rigour.

Could someone shed light on this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You say that you can represent the vector by the components for a given basis, and those components form a vector $v\in\mathbb{F}^n$ that can be written as a vector column... you seem to understand it, what is the question? Sorry if it's myself getting confused here...

Comment: That's what the notes claim. I am unable to bridge the connection into representing the column matrix as components of vector.

Comment: I'm puzzled too: If I understand the question correctly, you're happy with the notation $(v^1, \ldots, v^n)$ to represent the vector $\bf v$ (given a basis), but you're discontent with the notation $\pmatrix{v^1\\ \vdots \\v^n}$? This is simply just a different way of arranging the components.

Comment: @Travis Why is it that once a basis has been chosen, any vector can be represented by just its components? This might get the ball rolling.

Comment: @Travis That was what I was asking as well. Representing the vector as column or otherwise shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: @Mathematicing Sorry, I'm not sure I understand that question exactly either, but maybe it would be helpful to say that one can think of the desire to be able to do this as the motivation for the *definition* of basis: A basis $(E_1, \ldots, E_n)$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb F$ is an (ordered) set so that for any vector $v \in V$ there are unique coefficients $v^1, \ldots, v^n$ such that $v = \sum v^a E_a$. Then, it is a theorem that any such $V$ admits a basis.

Comment: (It is another theorem that the cardinality $n$ of all bases of $V$ are the same, and this is by definition, as you probably know, the dimension of $V$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you will see connection if you write $\vec{v}=v^1{\vec{e_1}} + v^2{\vec{e_2}} + \dots+ v^n{\vec{e_n}} $ and you write this equation in the matrix form $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}   \vec{e_1} & \vec{e_2} & \dots & \vec{e_n}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}   v^1 \\ v^2 \\ \dots \\ v^n\end{bmatrix}$,

but $\begin{bmatrix}   \vec{e_1} & \vec{e_2} & \dots &\vec{e_n}\end{bmatrix}=   \begin{bmatrix}   \ 1 & 0 & \dots &\ 0  \\  \ 0 & 1 & \dots &\ 0  \\ \ \dots & \dots & \dots &\ \dots  \   \\ 0 & 0 & \dots &\ 1 \end{bmatrix}= I \  \ \ \ $ - $ \ $identity matrix
  hence we have $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}   v^1 \\ v^2 \\ \dots \\ v^n\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Or...
define a bijective map $T_{B}$ from the vector space V to $F^{n}$...

Answer (score 1):

I think this can clarify a little bit:

> **Proposition** The representation of any vector $\vec{v}$ in terms of basis vectors
>   $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ is unique.

*Proof.* Suppose that $v$ is represented as both
$$\vec{v} = \sum_{j=1}^n v^j e_j\quad\text{and}\quad\vec{v}=\sum_{j=1}^n v^{\prime j} e_j.$$

Eliminating $\vec{v}$ gives
$$0 = \sum_{j=1}^n (v^j-v^{\prime j}) e_j.$$

Since $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ constitute a basis, they are linearly independent and each $(v^j-v^{\prime j}) = 0$. That is, $v^j=v^{\prime j}$, so that the representation must be unique.

---

Now you can use the **unique** components $v^1,v^2,\dots,v^n$ to represent the vector $\vec{v}$ for the given basis $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ as a column vector $\begin{pmatrix} v^1 \\ v^2 \\ \vdots \\ v^n \end{pmatrix}$ if you want.